# Check if a value exists in array using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB version 3.2. and i want to check if a string is exist in an array of string, i want to use the regex so if just a part of the given string is exist in a string in the array, that record should be returned.
here's an example of a record:

```
{
    name: "initiative 1",
    portfolioItems: ["Non clinical", "ITS portfolio", "Lean"]
}
```

the following query does not work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
            { 'portfolioItems' : { $in: [/term/] } }
    }
])
```

is there anyway to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match:
    {"portfolioItems":{'$regex':"^it", '$options': 'i'}}
}
])
```

The symbol `^` used to start from the first of string. If u don't need it. You can remove it.

Your query become

```
 {
    $match:
    {"portfolioItems":{'$regex':"^"+term, '$options': 'i'}}
}
```

Comment: still the query return no results.

Comment: I run the same in my local using Robo3T and worked fine.

Comment: yes it works fine on shell too. bug in my node app didn't work !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the pattern in each element of array.
Try this :

```
{ 'portfolioItems' : { $regex: [/term/] } }
```

Comment: But there is no element which contains "term", so results will be empty. Have you tried another element.

Comment: `{
    $match:
    {"portfolioItems":{'$regex':"^it", '$options': 'i'}}
}`

Try with this

Comment: `term` is javascript variable used to store the search term. `+` used to concatenate with `^`. It is not a static string like `"term"` that you entered in the comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for informing me. I didn't have much idea about this